# As in swiper slide, make an active link only for the active slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

Friends, please tell me how to make the link active, only in the active slide? And in about everyone else, hide her.

https://codepen.io/Cheizer/pen/OJLWREZ

```
var s6 = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
       spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        slideToClickedSlide: true,
        navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
         clickable: true,
  }, 
});

var el = $('.swiper-container .swiper-slide');

 $(el).each(function(i,el) {

if($(this).activeIndex){

$('a').show();

}else{

$('a').hide();

}

 });
```

Doing so doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things here:

1. CSS way

   ```
   <style>
       .swiper-slide a {
           display:none
       }
       .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active a {
         display:block
       }

   </style>
   ```
2. JS way

To find which slide has changed you can use following

```
mySwiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  console.log(mySwiper.realIndex, 'slide changed');
});
```

All you have to do at this point is update a element inside that slide & update other slides to hide link.
e.g. https://codepen.io/tsvecak/pen/abowYJW

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had adapted the answer so instead of hiding and showing the anchor tag it changes the `tabIndex` value of the current slide to 1.

My problem was that as soon as I made the carousel loop it stopped working.

The solution was to change `realIndex` to `activeIndex`.

```
const swiperSlides = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide')

s6.on('slideChange', function() {
  const otherSlides = swiperSlides
  for (let index = 0; index < swiperSlides.length; index++) {
    const element = swiperSlides[index];
    element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute("tabIndex", -1);
  }

  const linkElemCurrentSlide = swiperSlides[s6.activeIndex].getElementsByTagName('a')
  linkElemCurrentSlide[0].setAttribute("tabIndex", 1);
});

$('.swiper-slide a').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});

    </script>
```